# Yii2 assign Asset to specific layout

Tags: yii2, assets

I have an application asset, which is registered for all views in application.

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        '/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        '/dist/css/adminlte.min.css',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700'


    ];
    public $js = [
        '/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js',
        '/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
        '/dist/js/adminlte.min.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [

    ];
}
```

Now, im trying to create a new one with different styles `AppAssetStats.php`, for other section of the site, and i want to assign my new asset to my layout `main_statistisc.php`. But i don't know how i can assign it to my new layout, currently i just use `registerJsFile` `registerCssFile`, but the default `AppAsset` styles stil remain. How i can use my new asset for the specific layout/view?

Answer (score 1):

Look, Assets are manually registered inside layouts, so your `application asset` which is registered for all views is likely just registered inside `layouts\main.php` view as:

```
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
...
use common\widgets\Alert;

AppAsset::register($this); // This one
?>
```

You can register `AppAssetStats.php` just the same way into your new layout `main_statistisc.php`, and set the new layout in the needed Controllers

Your layout `main_statistisc.php`:

```
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
...
AppAssetStats::register($this); // Your new asset
?>
```

And your Controller:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = 'main_statistisc'; //
```

Make sure that inside `main_statistisc.php` you do not have `AppAsset::register($this)` line, so that it won't conflict with your new asset

Additional information about Assets you can get from Yii2 Asset documentation:
[Yii2 Assets](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets)

..and additional info about layouts and view here:
[Yii2 Views and Layouts](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#layouts)

Answer (score 0):

Register asset file in layout file.

```
<?php
    use frontend\assets\AppAssetStats;
    AppAssetStats::register($this);
?>
```